# Translation: that which was to have been made

Tags: gerundive

I still remember `quod erat demonstrandum`, but ...`that which was to have been made` (actually `generated`)?

How would I best say that? I am thinking `quod erat factum`, but am unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like your `Quod erat demonstrandum` example suggests, you definitely need a [gerundive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerundive) form here :

> quod erat faciendum

Depending on the context, you might want to consider `facienda` (n. pl, "that which is to be made").

Comment: But if the plural 'facienda' is used, both 'quod' and 'erat' also need to be made plural. That isn't currently clear from your answer.

Comment: @cnread Sorry if my answer was a little terse : I meant `facienda`  as a standalone form, 'those <things> which are to be made'. Classic Latin probably wouldn't bother for the whole 'quae facienda erant' phrase unless to a specific effect. I just thought it sounded more idiomatic, but if OP needs a kind of closing formula like Q.E.D., `quod erat faciendum` and `quae erant facienda` both fit the bill. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Think mcadorel has provided the translation for "faciendum est"; not quite the same. Try "hoc (or quod) faciendum erat" giving: "this-ought-to-have-been-done/ made".